# Бот не реагирует на if

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telegram, telebot

Появилась еще одна проблема время больше чем указано в end_time, но бот продолжает писать в чате что 5 минут не прошло... Почему?

```
user_name = message.from_user.first_name
init_user('db/database.db', message.from_user.first_name)
init_user3('db/time.db', message.from_user.first_name)
currentLitres = getLitres('db/database.db', user_name, "beer")
endTimes = getTime('db/time.db', user_name, "end_time")
now_time = str(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2))
if now_time > endTimes:
    randomize = random.randint(1, 16)
    summ_litres = currentLitres + randomize
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<em>{user_name}, вы выпили - {randomize} л пива.</em>'+'\U0001F37A \n'
                                                f'Всего вы выпили - {summ_litres} л пива', parse_mode='html')
    setLitres('db/database.db', user_name, "beer", summ_litres)
    delTime('db/time.db', user_name)
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'<em>{user_name}, 5 минут еще не прошло! </em>', parse_mode='html')
print(endTimes)
print(now_time)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас время хранится в базе данных без даты?

Comment: В sqlite нет варианта datatime для столбцов, можно сохранить через text, int, real. Я использую text так как строчку с временем сейчас оно в int не переведет - ошибка

Comment: У вас в if сравнение строк на то какая из них больше. Как-то это не правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас вы сравниваете объект времени со строкой, на что if будет всегда реагировать как else, вам необходимо после получения времени из базы данных преобразовать endTimes в такой же объект времени:

```
end_time = time.strptime(endTimes, "%H:%M:%S")
```

Так же по комментарию от **newman** видно что вы сравниваете строки, удалите преобразование времени в строку

```
now_time = (datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2)).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Все равно ругается 
if now_time > end_time:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: @MrCrazy перепроверьте код, скорее всего вы забыли удалить преобразование в строку :)

Comment: А, да... Прошу прощение за беспокойство...

Answer (score 3):

Вы записываете даты в переменные endTimes и now_time. Как минимум переменная now_time точно является строкой, т.к. вы использовали `str()`. Подозреваю, что переменная endTimes - также строка.

Далее вы сравниваете эти две переменные как строки (strings). Они сравниваются посимвольно. '2' == '2' -> проверка продолжается, '0' < '1' -> возвращается false. Порядок, по которому сравниваются символы (почему 'A' > 'B' или 'Z' < '[')  можете посмотреть в любой таблице ascii.

Чтобы исправить ситуацию, вам нужно сравнивать переменные как объекты времени, как предложил *Jack Owest*.